# What's the difference between FireBug's console.log() and console.debug()?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console, firebug

A very simple code to illustrate the difference.

```
var x = [0, 3, 1, 2];
console.debug('debug', x);
console.log('log', x);
// above display the same result
x.splice(1, 2);
// below display kind of a different result
console.debug('debug', x);
console.log('log', x);
```

[alt text http://sixbytesunder.com/stuff/firebug_console.png](http://sixbytesunder.com/stuff/firebug_console.png)

The javascript value is exactly the same but console.log() displays it a bit differently than before applying `splice()` method. Because of this I lost quite a few hours as I thought splice is acting funny making my array multidimensional or something.

I just want to know why does this work like that. Does anyone know? :)

Comment: As Tim writes below: “More likely is that `console.log` and `console.debug`  simply behave differently by design. The source is available if you're curious.” You can also ask a question at [Firebug's discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/firebug) or [file a bug report](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/list).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the documentation, [it says](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console#Message_types):

> The console knows four different types
>   of messages, which are described below
>   […]
>
> See also the Console API for more
>   information about the different
>   commands.

A look on that page [shows](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.log.28object.5B.2C_object.2C_....5D.29) at `console.log`:

> If objects are logged, they will be
>   written not as static text, but as
>   interactive hyperlinks that can be
>   clicked to inspect the object in
>   Firebug's HTML, CSS, Script, or DOM
>   tabs.

So, I think that before the `splice`, the array is internally still an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array) (I know, it *is* a kind of object), but after the operation, you get a general object, at least internally. I know this is a weak explanation, but Firebug has more strange behaviour in the console.

BTW, the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) says nothing useful, but we can read in the section about `Array.prototype.splice` (§ 15.4.4.12):

> The `splice` function is intentionally
>   generic; it does not require that its
>   `this` value be an Array object.
>   Therefore it can be transferred to
>   other kinds of objects for use as a
>   method. Whether the `splice` function
>   can be applied successfully to a host
>   object is implementation-dependent.

Comment: Whether applied to an `Array` or not, `Array.prototype.splice` always returns an `Array`. That's in the spec.

Comment: @Tim: Yeah, I know, I talked about Firefox *internal* representation, which might be different than the spec prescribes.

Comment: Firebug's written in ordinary JavaScript and XUL. While JavaScript running in that environment has access to objects and extensions that JavaScript running in the page does not, I can't imagine that it will diverge from the spec. More likely is that `console.log` and `console.debug` simply behave differently by design. The source is available if you're curious.

Answer (score 1):

In Firebug 1.6a12 I get

```
debug [0, 3, 1, 2]  blog.php (line 80)
log [0, 3, 1, 2]
debug [0, 2]        blog.php (line 85)
log [0, 2]
```

The `debug()` lines include a link to the source line of the `console.debug()` line.